# Why is "will" used instead of "would" in "He said he will do everything in his power..."?

Tags: reported-speech

> He said he **will** do everything in his power to make sure the problems **is** not repeated.
>
> <sup>Source: [VOA Standard English, 0516-2013](https://www.lingq.com/lesson/0516-2013-292589/)</sup>

Why the bold words are not "would" and "were"?

The speaker had said "the **problem** is" and the source text was written false, so I'm not concerned about that part. I expected "will" had been written "would" as the sentence is an indirect speech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the reason is that the original statement is still true or it has not happened yet. Take a look at this explanation from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech/reported-speech-indirect-speech):

> We don’t need to change the tense in indirect speech if what a person
>   said is still true or relevant or has not happened yet. This often
>   happens when someone talks about the future, or when someone uses the
>   present simple, present continuous or present perfect in their
>   original words.